# Is it possible to do single sign on to Sharepoing using Oracle Access Manager (OAM) and Oracle Internet Directory (OID)

Tags: sharepoint-server, sso

Is it possible to use OID and OAM to single sign on (federation) to SharePoint?

Thanks

Khanh